# How to create a timeline diagram from multiple data values in sheets?

Tags: charts, google-spreadsheets

My data represents tasks and subtasks that I want to create a diagram from:

[image: data]

But as you can see in chart below, it treats multiple values as one value:

[image: chart]

I tried separating the values into different cells but it did not take the new column into account.

Does anybody have an idea how to achieve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Multiple tasks can be associated with a single predecessor, but a single task can't be associated with multiple predecessors.